# How to pass multiple parameters to IPN url to PayPal on Android?

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am implementing PayPal in my Android application and I want to send multiple parameters to PayPal as query string with IPN URL.

For example

```
http://www.example.com/ipn/txnId=12&cartId=12
```

but the problem is when I use this URL as IPN URL PayPal gives me an error.

I have tried with `URLEncoding` but again no successful payment.

If I try with single parameter it is working.

Example

```
http://www.example.com/ipn/txnId=12
```

I encountered a problem that PayPal is not accept `&` characters in string 
so I have tried to replace `&` with `&amp;` and also `\\&` but it didn't help either.

I know I can set multiple parameters into a single variable and pass it to PayPal but I want to pass multiple parameters like query string.

How can I have PayPal accept my payment with multiple parameters?

**EDIT**

Currently i am using this code for encode URL but it fails.

```
protected String addLocationToUrl(String url){

        if(!url.endsWith("?"))
            url += "?";

        List<NameValuePair> params = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txnId", "45"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cartId", "34"));



        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");

        url += paramString;


        return url;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From p20 of the developers guide at
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_PayflowPro_Guide.pdf

**Using Special Characters in Values**

Because the ampersand ( & ) and equal sign (=) characters have special meanings in the PARMLIST, name-value pairs like the following examples are not valid:

`NAME=Ruff & Johnson`

`COMMENT1=Level=5`

To use special characters in the value of a name-value pair, use a length tag. The length tag specifies the exact number of characters and spaces that appear in the value. The following name-value pairs are valid:

`NAME[14]=Ruff & Johnson`

`COMMENT1[7]=Level=5`

**UPDATE**

Following our conversation discussed in the [Android Disussion Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1134219#1134219) it became apprent that you were using the Paypal Payment API for Android.  Paypal do not provide support for multiple parameters in the IPN address using the Android Payment API.

One option would be to replace the `&` character with one that does not have a special meaning in URL's. Then parse the values from a single parameter value when recieved by your IPN listener, however you would also have to replace the subsequent `=` characters.

e.g. `http://www.example.com/ipn/params=txnId_12-cartId_12`

You stated that you require these additional parameters for validation purposes but validation should be implemented as outlined by paypal if it is to securely implemented.

Please read the [Overview of Instant Payment Notification](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro).  This describes the IPN process and what you need to validate IPN requests to your listening service.

You will also find an example for [Implementing an IPN listener in PHP](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNImplementation)

A complete list  of IPN message body parameters can be found  in the [Order Management Integration Guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_OrderMgmt_IntegrationGuide.pdf)

Comment: Do you know how to validate the notification when paypal sends the IPN? When have special chars?

Answer (score 1):

You could use "Custom" field but the same problem arises!
I Will try that usage of length tags with custom something like:

```
var1[5]=th&ee&var2[3]=t=o&var3[3]=one
```

---

***Values***

th&ee

t=o

one

---

is this it or am I missing something?

If all else fails I will replace the chars and reReplace them on the receiving end.